# activar puerto 443 en VPS con nginx

Tags: nginx, vps

Buenas soy un poco nuevo en esto.
La cuestión es que no se cargar la conexión(rechaza la conexión) Al querer entrar en el puerto 443 por HTTPS.

Tengo un Vps en una instancia de amazon aws de ubuntu 16 (con las confiuraciones de escucha del http/https)
En el servidor tengo la configuración de nginx
con una aplicación node.js corriendo en pm2 con frond end angular

Soy un poco nuevo en esto de los servidores la web carga correctamente con el dominio tal cual o directamente la ip con http. Pero si intento entrar por https rechaza la conexion. Nginx no soporta o no esta habilitado que pueda entrar por el puerto https.

Como puedo hacer para que el servidor no rechace e la conexión?

PD: Cuando no rechace la conexión configurare un balanceador de carga desde amazon para que funcione el certificado emitido por amazon

Aver si alguien me puedo ayudar gracias

Comment: Si no esta configurado el certificado no tendrás HTTPS. Tambien revisa el firewall.

Comment: en AWS el certificado se configura en el balanceador de carga y el balanceador de carga apunta a la instancia ( en el vps solo hay que habilitar el openssl del puerto 443) esto me funciona perfecto en APACHE pero en nginx no me esta funcionando.  PD: tengo habilitado en el proxy el puerto 443 pero nada

Comment: Toma en cuenta el puerto por el cual se comunican el balanceador y la instancia. ¿Qué tipo tipo de balanceador es? ¿aplicación, red o clásico?.